# testing tools for ruby on rails [unit testing that is testing each methods]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a live data and i have to test on live data in ruby on rails. Please suggest me best testing tools to test live data. And i am using sunspot solr to search data and how can i test the resultant data. Please help me to get good testing tools.

Answer (score 0):

The so called **Unit testing** is not a feature to be used live. It lays on the development environment, and its purpose is to check the behaviour of small pieces of your code.

If this is what you meant, than a sort of tools are available:

- Test::Unit, which is native from Ruby on Rails
- Rspec - http://rspec.info/

If this is not what you meant, than you need to better specify what does "test live data" means.

Comment: I have a data in database and i will make mysql query on respective models in controller. I have to test the result obtained by query. For some methods in controller i am using sunspot solr search to fetch the data. So i need a testing tool to test each method in controller.

Comment: You mean you need to check data consistency?